# Automatic Login to Desktop with Xubuntu Vivid 15.04?

Tags: xubuntu, login, lightdm

When I boot up the computer, I'd like it to boot right to the Xubuntu desktop, rather than prompting me to login with lightdm. I'm aware that I can set up lightdm to not ask me for a password, but it still requires me to click the login button to get to the desktop. Is it possible to just skip lightdm entirely and go right to the desktop?

Thanks!